# Check Windows Installer Version

Tags: windows-installer

I have checked my Add/Remove program panel and Components panel as well but could not find the version of Windows Installer on my machine. Can anybody please guide me in finding out the version of Windows Installer installed on any machine

Comment: How is this question related to a programming problem?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy It's related because developers often need to know what version of the installer is installed when installing dev tools.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Go into cmd(command prompt) or the run dialog (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and execute `msiexec -?`.
It will open a window containing your version at the top.

Comment: Running only `msiexec` should be [sufficient](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-do-i-find-out-what-windows-installer-is-on-my/4ef7a661-61bb-47ca-ba7e-05771edc41a1?msgId=1fecf808-10ab-4d5e-9eaf-dbdac25f8ed5). There is also a Microsoft KB [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438651) that covers this.